# How to remove Windows from a Windows/Ubuntu Machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

A few months ago I installed Ubuntu on my Windows laptop. 
I used the Ubuntu installation option to partition the drive in order to have both the Windows and Ubuntu operating systems.

I am ready to make the leap to Ubuntu.

**How can I completely remove Windows from my laptop?**

My goal is to do this without deleting my Ubuntu files, applications and settings.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/589097/remove-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer! Thank you Ubuntu help.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

Here is what I did:

1. insert Ubuntu installation CD
2. Restart Computer
3. When Ubuntu starts, choose option [like] "Try Ubuntu Without Making Any Changes to Your Computer"
4. once Ubuntu starts, open gparted.
5. Use gparted to delete the windows partition and increase the size of the Ubuntu partition.

Note: If there are any "key" icons showing in the gparted display, then right click on the corresponding partition and select the appropriate option (which I can't recall at the moment...) to remove the key. The key means the partition is "mounted" and can't be resized. Another tricky part for me was figuring out how to fill the newly unallocated space by increasing the size of my existing Ubuntu partition. The the Ubuntu partition that I wanted to "grow" was inside an "extended" partition. To "grow" the Ubuntu partition, you must first (in gparted) click on the extended partition in the list of available partitions. Only then (as I finally discovered), you will be able to use the "slider" to the extended partition (using the GUI) to fill the unallocated space. Once you have done that, you can then select the the Ubuntu partition that's inside the extended partition that you want to "grow" and use the slider to fill the available space for that one as well.

Comment: I believe the option is called "Force unmount".