# Remove Windows 8 and keep Ubuntu installed using Wubi

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04

My laptop came with Windows 7 installed. I updated it to Windows 8. I have installed Ubuntu using Wubi. Now I want to remove Windows 8 and use only Ubuntu. Is it possible to remove Windows 8 without losing data in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you read the [MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) wiki page yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but may be tricky depending on how you installed Ubuntu.

In ubuntu, install utility `gparted` using `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Run `sudo gparted`, choose your drive (most likely `/dev/sda`) and take a look at all partitions you have. If your setup was more or less normal, you should see at least 2 big partitions - one of `ext4` type (Linux/Ubuntu), and another of `NTFS` type (Windows). Using `gparted`, delete NTFS partition to reclaim space taken by it. Theoretically, you can resize your `ext4` partition to encompass whole drive space, but practically you cannot do that on running system (but you *can* do it from Live CD or using Parted Magic USB stick).

To make is safe and easy, you can simply create another `ext4` partition occupying space of old NTFS partition, and then mount it into some empty directory, like `/data` (`mkdir` it first!). To make this partition mount permanent, you should add a line like this into `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=b516743e-a3df-42d4-a5af-e8a358c1c8be /data ext4 defaults 0
```

To find UUID for all partitions (including just created ones), simply inspect output of command:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

One word of caution: try to not resize of move your /boot partition. If you do, it is not catastrophical, but you may have to run Ubuntu boot-loader recovery - because this may screw up boot-loader (grub) configuration. If your root Linux partition `/` is separate from `/boot`, it is should be safe to resize it (but still DO BACKUP!).